# gostaria de saber como eu faço esse efeito aque em css

Tags: javascript, css

**gostaria de saber como eu faço esse efeito a baixo de um cd aque em css**
[image: efeito]

**meu site e esse quero fazer aonde a seta ta indicando**
[image: site]

Comment: Isso não é um efeito, é uma imagem... Ou será que o que você quer é, dada uma imagem "normal", criar por baixo um elemento redondo com a mesma imagem pra parecer um CD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa ajustar o `border-radius` do seu elemento, se ele for suficientemente grande o elemento vai ficar redondo:

```css
img {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.capa {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
}

.cd {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="capa" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Tux.png">
<img class="cd" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Tux.png">
```